# @font-face position issue on Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, font-face

I have embedded a few fonts from http://fontface.codeandmore.com/
And it works great in Win but Mac. The problem is the position recognition in Mac OS. Attached  shows the problem. Padding and margin issues. Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Also the page can be checked here: http://sneakyrascal.com/nxt-bs/

[image: mac issue]

Comment: This is a good example of using sprites actually wasting your time (what using sprites normally does) *and* increasing the amount of markup you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Hi used to this online convert font in all format with css

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Hi - this actually doesn't upload 2 of my fonts because of copyright issue. Do you think the rendering issue might be because of the generator?

Comment: it's ok but you upload only .ttf fonts and this site convert to all version

Comment: please convert the font webkit of this site and apply your website than check to i thing your problem is short list ....